# Difference between List <? extends interface> and List <interface>

Tags: java, interface, extends

I have this interface:

```
public interface IModel extends Serializable{
    boolean isOnDb();       
}
```

I have an Object that implements the interface IModel :

```
public class Media implements Serializable, IModel {
   @Override
   public boolean isOnDb() {
      return isOnDb;
   } 
}
```

I want to create a `List` where I can put objects that implement the interface IModel. Something like this:

```
  List<? extends IModel> list= new ArrayList<>();
  Media media = new Media();
  list.add(m);
```

the code above doesn't compile. But I have no error if I do :

```
  List<IModel> list= new ArrayList<>();
  Media media = new Media();
  list.add(m);
```

What's the difference between `List<? extends IModel>` and `List<IModel>`?
Thank you in advance

Comment: A `List<SomethingExtendsIModel>` is a `List<? extends IModel>`, but not a `List<IModel>`.